# Change video quality with sources pointing to different quality versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

**Goal:**

I am trying to implement a control with as little code clutter as possible that will allow the change of quality of a video.

**Preferences:**

The following is what I am given, and I would rather work around it. I am open to using pre-built plugins or a javascript/jquery hack, but would rather not go for a solution that involves reinventing (me or you) the wheel (require the building of a custom video control scheme), but would take it as a last result.

**EDIT:**

Sorry. Did not mean to have that correlation, as the urls did not reflect any sort of pattern. I oversimplified it, not assuming people would look at the urls for a pattern. But thank you for that start, as I can probably work with that. Sorry again. I will change the urls to not have any pattern.

```
<video controls preload>
   <source label="fullHD" src="http://v.com/lorem.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source label="720p"   src="http://v.com/ipsum.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
   <source label="360p"   src="http://v.com/dolor.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Thank you in advance for anybody who can give some insight.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry for asking. Turns out I was able to solve it pretty much all by myself. Hate those moments. Here is the solution I came up with, which just involves copying the `<source>` I need based on the `label` attribute, deleting it, and prepending it into the `<video>` element:

**HTML**

```
<div class='vidcontainer'>
   <select class='qualitypick' autocomplete='off'>
      <option selected>fullHD</option>
      <option>720p</option>
      <option>360p</option>
   </select>
   <video controls preload>
      <source label="fullHD" src="http://v.com/lorem.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source label="720p"   src="http://v.com/ipsum.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
      <source label="360p"   src="http://v.com/dolor.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.qualitypick').change(function(){ 

      //Have several videos in file, so have to navigate directly
      video = $(this).parent().find("video");
      
      //Need access to DOM element for some functionality
      videoDOM = video.get(0);

      curtime = videoDOM.currentTime;  //Get Current Time of Video
      source = video.find("source[label=" + $(this).textContent + "]"); //Copy Source

      source.remove();                 //Remove the source from select
      video.prepend(source);           //Prepend source on top of options
      video.load();                    //Reload Video
      videoDOM.currentTime = curtime;  //Continue from video's stop
      videoDOM.play();                 //Resume video
   })
})
```

Although this was not my intention, I hope my answer is of some use. Sorry again for asking before thinking it through.

Comment: And do you think, It will change video quality by just picking the static value from select box?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need many `source` tags. One is enough, however, you need to change the value of the `source` attribute, which is `src`.

```js
var map={'fullHD':'1080p','720p':'720p','360p':'360p'};


function changeQ(quality){
     $('source','video#player').attr('src','http://v.com/'+map[quality]);
      $('span#pp').html(map[quality]);
     console.log($('source','video#player').attr('src'))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Quality
 (<span id="pp"></span>)</button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="#" onclick="changeQ('fullHD')">FullHD</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" onclick="changeQ('720p')">720p</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" onclick="changeQ('360p')">360p</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>


<video id="player" width="400" controls>
 <source src="http://v.com/1080p" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I made the urls like that to simplify the issue, and did not think people would look at the pattern. That is my fault. Plus, this may very well be enough for me to work with, so thank you for that.